# javascript use for loop to set .jpg image in html page

Tags: javascript, for-loop

This is my entrance into programming, I have been working with JS for
two weeks for school. The project is to build a website for a rug
shop.

This week's assignment is writing a table and populating the fields
using arrays accessed by for loop. The arrays have to be stored in
separate JS page, and functions are in the actual HTML page.

Here are my arrays on its own js page:

```
function getID()
{
  var url = window.location.toString();
  var i = 0;
  if(url.indexOf("?id=")>0)
  {
    var start = url.lastIndexOf("?id=")+ 4;
    i = url.substring(start);
  }
  return i;
}

//array containing names of individual rugs in inventory
var aName = new Array();
aName[0] = "Red/Blue3x5";
aName[1] = "Blue/Yellow5x8";
aName[2] = "VintagePersian7x10";
aName[3] = "Oversize.20x20";

//array containing prices on rug inventory 
var aPrice = new Array();
aPrice[0] = "$299.00";
aPrice[1] = "$700.00";
aPrice[2] = "$2,999.00";
aPrice[3] = "$25,000.00";

//array containing images individual rugs in inventory
var aImage = Array();
aImage[0] = src="red.blue.3x5.jpg";
aImage[1] = src="blue.yellow.5x8.jpg";
aImage[2] = src="vintage.persian.7x10.jpg";
aImage[3] = src="oversize.20x20.jpg";
```

Here's the segment of HTML page table where the images should appear
in the first column :

```
 <tbody>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                //tabel header
                document.write("<table border='1' rules='rows' cellspacing='0'>");
                document.write("<tr>");
                document.write("<th>&nbsp;</th><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Order</th>");
                document.write("</tr>");                

                //loop through aName aray & write results 
                for (var i =0; i < aName.length ; i++) {
                document.write("<tr>");

                //initialize empty array
                var pictures = [];

                //insert place holder
                var image = new Image;

                //set src attribute
                image.src = 'images/' + aImage[i];
                pictures.push(image);

                document.write("<td>");             
                document.write("<image src='aImage[i]' width='50' height='20'" + " />");
                document.write("</td>");
                document.write("<td>" + aName[i] + "</td>");
                document.write("<td>" + aPrice[i] + "</td>");

                //to create hyperlinks for products 
                document.write("<td><span class='link'><a href='#' title='price'>price</a></span>"); 
                }       

            </script>
        </tbody>
```

The table appears with the proper columns, but the place where the
image should appear displays a blank spot, and debugging shows:

> "Failed
>   to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" message.

Comment: This looks like a typo: `var image = new Image;`, you should do `var image = new Image();`

Comment: Can you tell us the folder structure of where you are storing your images? For example, if you were to store them in a folder called "Images" at the site root then the relative path would be "/Images/whatever.jpg" . If you were storing them at site root then you  the path would be "/whatever.jpg" . Right now you are just saying the src is "whatever.jpg"

Comment: Open console of browser and check whats the `src` value set to `img` tag

Comment: you use src='images/aImage[i]' in img Tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i cleaned this up a bit and fixed the `<img>` for you. 
i added comments to the code to help you. let me know if you need anything else. please see the notes below for more information about my suggested changes. good luck!

1. i don't think you need to instantiate new Image objects when
   you're writing the `<img>` tags to the DOM.
2. i named the external script `data.js` and i included it with a
   `<script>` tag within the `<html>` tag.
3. you need to make sure that the images are saved in a directory
   called `images` on the same level and in the same directory as the
   html file. others have mentioned this above. let us know if you need more clarification.

```js
// this is "data.js"

function getID () {
  var url = window.location.toString();

  var i = 0;

  if (url.indexOf("?=") > 0) {
    var start = url.lastIndexOf("?id=") + 4;
    i = url.substring(start);
  }

  return i;
}

var aName = [];
aName[0] = "Red/Blue3x5";
aName[1] = "Blue/Yellow5x8";
aName[2] = "VintagePersian7x10";
aName[3] = "Oversize.20x20";

aPrice[0] = "$299.00";
aPrice[1] = "$700.00";
aPrice[2] = "$2,999.00";
aPrice[3] = "$25,000.00";

// new - i fixed the declarations below
var aImage = [];
aImage[0] = "red.blue.3x5.jpg";
aImage[1] = "blue.yellow.5x8.jpg";
aImage[2] = "vintage.persian.7x10.jpg";
```

```html
<html>
  <!--  includes the othe script you created -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="data.js"></script>
  <!-- we'll assume there are other tags such as <head> and <body> -->
  <tbody>
    <!--  your inline js -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // table header
        document.write("<table border='1' rules='rows' cellspacing='0'>");
        document.write("<tr>");
        document.write("<th>&nbsp;</th><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Order</th>");
        document.write("</tr>");

        // loop through aName aray & write results
        for (var i = 0; i < aName.length; i++) {
          document.write("<tr>");
          document.write("<td>");

          // new - i fixed the tag below
          var imgSrc = "images/" + aImage[i];
          document.write("<img src=" + imgSrc + " width='50' height='20'/>");
          
          document.write("</td>");
          document.write("<td>" + aName[i] + "</td>");
          document.write("<td>" + aPrice[i] + "</td>");

          // new -- not sure where you're getting the hyperlink url's from but i can help with this as well when you figure it out
          // to create hyperlinks for products
          document.write("<td><span class='link'><a href='#' title='price'>price</a></span>");
        }

    </script>
  </tbody>
  <!-- closing other tags -->
</html>
```

This code still would not display images and returned "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" error in debugger. I fooled around with your updates and made it work by modifying one line:

document.write("");

changed to:
document.write("");

Now it works perfectly, thank you!!

Comment: Thanks Johnathan, that works. I did have to change this line or it still could not find the image files:

Comment: Thanks, Johnathan, that works. I did have to break that one line into two separate commands or it still could not find the image files:  document.write("<img src=" + imgSrc + " width='50' height='20'/>");  changed to: -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------document.write("<image src=" + imgSrc);-------------------------------------document.write(" width='50' height='20' />");

Answer (score 0):

It cannot find your image files. Check the paths you have set:

src="picture.jpg" = picture.jpg is located in the same folder as the current page

src="images/picture.jpg" = picture.jpg is located in the images folder in the current folder

src="/images/picture.jpg" =     picture.jpg is located in the images folder at the root of the current web

src="../picture.jpg"  = picture.jpg is located in the folder one level up from the current folder